# apt-fast checksum error detected on kali linux

Tags: apt, kali-linux, checksum

I installed apt-fast to fasten the download process of apt-get but when i try to upgrade an application apt-fast don't download the .deb files instead it reports an error saying there is a checksum error detected and the downloaded files are not completed[image]

How can i avoid this error?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you’re not the only one to have [such issues](https://github.com/ilikenwf/apt-fast/issues). Since you’re new to Linux I suggest you remove `apt-fast` and stick to the basic system.

It’s also worth pointing out that [Kali Linux isn’t intended for users new to Linux](http://docs.kali.org/introduction/should-i-use-kali-linux).

Comment: I use apt-fast because the internet connection I have is not fast

Comment: `apt-fast` can’t download anything faster than your Internet connection will allow...

Comment: Yes but it does divide the task and download simultaneously . Anyway I found that it was my DNS complication and used Google's DNS and I change the source list to a mirror location to Kali's repository